# Prisma ignores TinyInt Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, prisma, remix

I'm testing prisma in a remix.js application.

So I have the following MySQL table for Users

```
 desc Users;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| uid       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(45) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| email     | varchar(45) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| password  | varchar(99) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| CreatedAt | datetime    | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
| status    | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | 1                   |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Using after install and do the first introspection, I've added the last column that suposed to be a Boolean but MariaDB converts it as TinyInt(1). So far so good.
Then, after it, I did a new **prisma db pull** and my Users Schema is now:

```
model Users {
  uid       Int         @id @unique(map: "id_UNIQUE") @default(autoincrement())
  name      String      @unique(map: "name_UNIQUE") @db.VarChar(45)
  email     String      @unique(map: "email_UNIQUE") @db.VarChar(45)
  password  String      @db.VarChar(99)
  CreatedAt DateTime    @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  status    Int?        @default(1) @db.TinyInt
  enderecos enderecos[]
}
```

The problem happens when I try to retrieve data.
If a do a console.log of a simple **Users.findMany()** i get:

```
[
  {
    name: 'lada',
    email: 'uma@lada.com',
    CreatedAt: '2023-05-11T21:35:02.000Z',
    uid: 1,
    password: '$2a$12$WXIy/aWr6Y12Y08SBcUeWOCVZ6S4GBK/EZeGpm0j5FF4yUAF7ATFa'
  },
  {
    name: 'teste',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    CreatedAt: '2023-05-11T21:38:47.000Z',
    uid: 2,
    password: '$2a$12$FXSAGgkAMWZhAhPwVMhQYOCCAZFqGCFXm9aQSe3QbQXL56v9cptv2'
  },
  {
    name: 'James Bond',
    email: 'james.bonda@gmail.com',
    CreatedAt: '2023-05-15T06:34:33.000Z',
    uid: 3,
    password: '$2a$12$WelH9VyYBoOSYXFbW7/9N.dKIEnWnTQ6tKUOGYqISqWTpma0wEiPO'
  },
  {
    name: 'John Smith',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    CreatedAt: '2023-05-15T06:40:18.000Z',
    uid: 4,
    password: '$2a$12$hpxIuxyQTXzaLpBT3PwVFOhVQiuYU5ncQw1UnV038rCYg6GKAx1AK'
  }
]
```

without the 'status' column.
And when creating a new User I force to insert the status column  `const users = await prisma.Users.create({data: {name, email, password: hashedPassword, status: 1}});` I get the following error:

```
18 
  19 const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 12);
  20 
→ 21 const users = await prisma.Users.create({
       data: {
         name: 'John Snow',
         email: 'johnsnow@gmail.com',
         password: '$2a$12$uppcEWaYGH8RtC1o/PMTpuoFPeQ3S21or96LysLFAeRnnFRnUI2Da',
         status: 1
         ~~~~~~
       }
     })

Unknown arg `status` in data.status for type UsersCreateInput. Did you mean `name`? Available args:
type UsersCreateInput {
  name: String
  email: String
  CreatedAt?: DateTime
  password: String
  enderecos?: enderecosCreateNestedManyWithoutUsersInput
}
```

I see there is not **status** in the `type UsersCreateInput` but I'm using javascript, and I don't know where or if I could edit this type.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nothing like write a complete question to realize how stupid I am!

After applying `prisma db pull` I forgot to regenerate the Prisma Client.

So the solution is:

```
npx prisma db pull
npx prisma generate
```